# PHP performance, reading from a file or reading for database?

Tags: php, caching

I need to know this information please, I use the **`file()`** function in PHP which reads an entire file into an array; that file contains serialized objects that I unserialize and use.

On the other hand, I have the option of storing information in MySQL and retrieving it using a query.

Knowing that this operation is expected to be done millions of times a day, is it better for PHP to read and unserialize data from file or from database? I have no statistics in hand :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good question, I shall be following this for a decisive answer.

Comment: Fastest: reading from memory. Use a caching system.

Comment: I think the usual answer for these types of questions is that you can't know what will perform better for your particular environment until you try both options and measure the performance.  There are many, many unspecified details that can affect the outcome.

Comment: At least, a database is also stored in a file. But you have the complex database layer that caches your data in memory. So I would prefer the database.

Comment: setup a prototype and benchmark it.

Comment: I suspect that the real bottleneck will be unserialising the data rather than the method of reading it.

Comment: After writing my answer I've noticed the 'caching' tag on your post. Can you clarify what exactly you are *doing* that you need this advice for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database. Database, database, a thousand [or million, in ths case] times database.

The only exception I can think of is that if *every* request requires *every* bit of data contained in this file.

MySQL is much more efficient at:

- managing large sets of data
- indexing, searching, and sorting data sets
- retrieving random bits and pieces of data

Comment: Actually I didn't know that in case of a persistent connection, MySQL will advantageously store data that is permanently requested in memory, so that it can be retrieved in 0.000...... seconds.

Comment: I shouldn't underestimate the power of databases :) flat files always file compared to that, even for a simple file read VS persistent database connection

Comment: Wouldn't the physical location of the database matter? If the DB is on the same physical server, no doubt a DB is a better option, but if it's on another server, this would introduce network latency that file reading wouldn't suffer from. Would a DB still be the better choice?

Comment: @xbonez generally/ideally your mySQL server is 'adjacent' to the application server on the LAN and latency is negligible. It's usually beneficial to offload the CPU/IO/RAM overhead of running MySQL to another machine so that they are not competing for resources when things get busy.

Comment: @xbonez your question is totally logical, given that a powerful cache system (such as Memcache for PHP) handles persistent connection and multiple servers, a weak database instead would be the wrong choice. But anyway, whether using Memcached (files) or MySQL (database), the latency should be measured carefully :)

Answer (score 4):

Memory is going to be faster, and generally mysql will cache common queries in memory (unless the query cache is disabled for some reason). If the server is remote network latency may need to be accounted for.

Now, there is a better way to do this. Use APC or a local memcached server to store this information. This is your best option if it doesn't change or changes infrequently.

Comment: Next to APC / memcached solution, there's also the option of creating a php daemon which simply hands out the array, without any need to actually serialize the array in order to save it. However, out of all the answers, this is a proper one, +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will use Memcached for data that is constantly being READ ONLY ! If there are any variable data (performing frequent SET and GET on it) it should be handled by a database actually.. :)

Comment: It depends how often it changes actually. If your code is set up with a read through paradigm, you can issue a delete if the data changes, then the next time its read, it will pull from source.

Comment: @datasage Totally accurate, I forgot about that too :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that document based databases are always faster than RDBMS like MySQL.
But you won t notice it unless you have huge amount of records and data. In your case it depends on which method is handy for you. Depends on if you have relationships between your data that need some kind of integrity and an easy way to query.